# Spring Ldap authentication without attributes retrieve

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security, spring-ldap

I would like to authenticate user through Ldap and Spring security.
I use database to give roles to user so I have implemented LdapAuthoritiesPopulator interface :

```
@Service("myAuthPopulator")
public class MyAuthoritiesPopulator implements LdapAuthoritiesPopulator {

    @Autowired
    private UserServices userServices;
    static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyAuthoritiesPopulator.class);

    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(DirContextOperations userData, String username) {
        Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();
        try{
            com.domain.User user = userServices.getByUsersEnabled(username);
            if (user==null){
                LOG.error("Threw exception in MyAuthoritiesPopulator::getGrantedAuthorities : User doesn't exist into DART database" );
            }
            else{
                //Use this if a user can have different roles
//              for(Role role : user.getRole()) {
//                  authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRole()));
//              }
                authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getRole().getRole()));
                return authorities;
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            LOG.error("Threw exception in MyAuthoritiesPopulator::getGrantedAuthorities : " + ErrorExceptionBuilder.buildErrorResponse(e)); }
        return authorities;
    }
}
```

Then I have this code to authenticate user through binding

```
@Configuration
protected static class AuthenticationConfiguration extends
GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myAuthPopulator")
    LdapAuthoritiesPopulator myAuthPopulator;
    @Override
    public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{ 
          auth.ldapAuthentication()
          .contextSource()
            .url("ldaps://vldp.floal:636/")
          .and()   
          .userDnPatterns("CN={0},CN=ProxyUsers,CN=fdam,dc=fg,dc=local")
            .ldapAuthoritiesPopulator(myAuthPopulator);                
    }
}
```

Here I have a problem: user can't retrieve his attributes so I receive Spring error:

```
ERROR o.s.s.w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user.
```

Is it possible to make logon only with binding without get attributes? 
For exaple with this code:

```
AndFilter filter = new AndFilter(); 
filter.and(new EqualsFilter("CN", commonName)); 
boolean isAuthenticated = ldapTemplate.authenticate("CN=ProxyUsers,CN=fgadam", filter.encode(), password);
```

This is my login page:

```
<body class="hold-transition login-page">
    <div class="login-box">
        <div class="login-logo">
            <b>DART</b> Sign in
        </div>
        <!-- /.login-logo -->
        <div class="login-box-body">
            <p class="login-box-msg">Sign in to start your session</p>
            <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
                <div th:if="${param.error}">
                    <script>
                        notifyMessage("Invalid username and password!", 'error');
                    </script>
                </div>
<!--                <div th:if="${param.logout}">
                    <script>
                        notifyMessage("You have been logged out!", 'error');
                    </script>
                </div> -->
                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                    <input id="username" name="username" type="text"
                        class="form-control" placeholder="Username"> <span
                        class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                    <input id="password" name="password" type="password"
                        class="form-control" placeholder="Password"> <span
                        class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-8">
                        <div class="checkbox icheck">
                            <label> <input type="checkbox"> Remember Me
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.col -->
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <button id="signinButton" type="submit"
                            class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Sign In</button>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.col -->
                </div>
            </form>

            <div >
                <img th:src="@{/static/assets/dist/img/login.jpg}" class="img-responsive" alt="FCA">
            </div>

        </div>
        <!-- /.login-box-body -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.login-box -->
</body>
```

Maybe I might retrieve them with a search through manager account. Thanks

Comment: the org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator  actually only performs an ldap_bind operation and does not retrieve attributes.

Comment: it seems that other people have my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831630/why-does-spring-securitys-bindauthenticator-require-read-permissions-for-users

Comment: I could provide an XML-based config, if this helps